# Rails Active Record .all method deletes all records saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot understand what happened, but it seems that after all call .all method my records in one specific DB table disappear. If I run rake db:seed, table fills up. But once I call .all records disappear.

```
rake db:seed
```

After it I can see all records in UI.

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > reload!
Reloading...
=> true
```

Here I still see records.

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Url.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Here they disappear from DB and UI

It is the same for manual record creating via UI and console.
How could it be? How to fix it?

Comment: did you load your console in test environment?

Comment: Dumb question, but I'm assuming you didn't append `--sandbox` when you loaded the rails console, right?

Comment: @Vimsha I work in development environment.

Comment: @Teeg, no I didn't. And I don't need it, obviously.

Comment: @MikhailChuprynski That's correct. Just making sure. Hmm, very odd problem. I can't reproduce on my end. It is curious though that you're not seeing any `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` messages around your `.save`. At least for me (in my rails 4 app), I get those messages for every db call (on save, destroy, etc). It almost sounds like your entire console session is wrapped in one huge transaction that gets rolled back on reload. Are you by chance using any gems (relating to transactions, active record, the console itself, etc) that might be interfering in this manner?

Comment: @Teeg The problem appears only with one table - Url. Others work correctly in the same console window.. I cannot even imagine, what I've broken.. I reviewed my gems and the only suspicious one is  'delayed_job_active_record', but I do not use it in the console..

Comment: Try length or size instead of count and see if that makes any difference? I presume no after save/commit hooks right? Also take a look at the db after every step to see exactly if/when that record actually goes missing.

Comment: If you're using console, in another window you might try to `tail -f log/development.log` to see when the record is saved and if it is deleted.

Comment: @Swards there is nothing related. My work with console doesn't affect it at all.

Comment: @Tim All the same, reload! make them all to be 0

Comment: @MikhailChuprynski you may need to put together a minimal test case and share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your model name from Url to something else.  You can still use the same table name (urls) by using `set_table_name 'urls'`.

Comment: This crossed my mind as well but it would be very odd and unfortunate if it was the case.